# Typescript: How to cast or assign an object to a type with fewer properties? (From Big to Small)

Tags: typescript

I have three Objects(Classes), they're like following:

```
class A {

  public value1: string;
  public value2: string;
  public value3: string;
  public value4: string;
  public value5: string;

}

class B {

  public value1: string;
  public value2: string;

}

class C {

  public value3: string;
  public value4: string;
  public value5: string;

}
```

Now I have a JSON which is like:

```
{
  "value1": "ONE",
  "value2": "TWO",
  "value3": "THREE",
  "value4": "FOUR",
  "value5": "FIVE"
}
```

I'm wondering if there is any clean way to cast class `A` to class `B` and class `C`?

I tried this method, but after `map`, class `B` has all 5 properties from `A` instead of the 2 properties defined on `B`.

```
class B {

  public value1: string;
  public value2: string;

  constructor(item: A) {
    Object.assign(this, item);
  }

}


let arr1: A[{"value1":"ONE","value2":"TWO","value3":"THREE","value4":"FOUR","value5":"FIVE"}];
let arr2 = arr1.map(item => new B(item));
```

```
Result: B -> {"value1":"ONE","value2":"TWO","value3":"THREE","value4":"FOUR","value5":"FIVE"}]
instead of 
B -> {"value1":"ONE","value2":"TWO"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking typescript to modify value
Typescript doesn't run your code, only compiles and checks for type safety

What you can do is: define null props to B class, and check keys

```
class A {
  public value1: string
  public value2: string
  public value3: string
  public value4: string
  public value5: string
}
class B {
  public value1: string = undefined // <-- define
  public value2: string = undefined // <-- define
  constructor (item: A) {
    const keys = Object.keys(item) // get items keys
    const thisKeys = Object.keys(this) // get this class keys
    const limitedItem = keys.reduce((newObj, key) => { // combine same keys
      if (thisKeys.includes(key)) {
        newObj[key] = item[key]
      }
      return newObj
    }, {})
    Object.assign(this, limitedItem) // asign to this class
  }
}

const arr1 = [{ value1: '1', value2: '2', value3: '3', value4: '4', value5: '5' }]
let arr2 = arr1.map(item => new B(item))
console.log('arr2', arr2)

// arr2 [ B { value1: '1', value2: '2' } ]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for code example and explanation! It works very well thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From [TypeScript Deep Dive](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html)

> ### Type Assertion vs. Casting
>
> The reason why it's not called "type casting" is that casting generally implies some sort of runtime support. However, type assertions are purely a compile time construct and a way for you to provide hints to the compiler on how you want your code to be analyzed.

A type assertion tells the Typescript compiler that you already know that a value may be safely treated as another type, even though it cannot be verified through static analysis.

### Type Assertion Example

```
class A {
    constructor(public val1: string, public val2: string, public val3: string,
        public val4: string, public val5: string) {}
}

class B {
    constructor(public num1: number, public num2: number) {}
}
```

Since type `A` and `B` do not overlap, the Typescript compiler will issue a warning if you try and assign an instance of `A` to a `B`.

```
let a = new A('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
let b: B = a;  // Error: Type 'A' is missing the following properties from type 'B': num1, num2
```

Using a Type Assertion, you could tell the compiler to ignore the mismatched types, which in this case is a bad idea.

```
let a = new A('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
let b: B = <any> a;
let b2: B = a as any;
```

What you are asking is how to limit the properties that are assigned when copying an instance of a class that has more properties than the target class. In your example, a straightforward approach would be to create `static` factory functions (i.e. specialized constructors) for `B` and `C` that accept instances of `A` as shown below.

## Example using Static Factory Functions

```
class A {
    constructor(public val1: string, public val2: string, public val3: string,
        public val4: string, public val5: string) {}
}

class B {
    constructor(public val1: string, public val2: string) {}

    static constructFromA(a: A): B {
        return new B(a.val1, a.val2);
    } 
}

class C {
    constructor(public val3: string, public val4: string, public val5: string) {}

    static constructFromA(a: A): C {
        return new C(a.val3, a.val4, a.val5);
    } 
}


let a = new A('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
let b = B.constructFromA(a);
let c = C.constructFromA(a);

console.log(JSON.stringify(b, null, 2));
console.log(JSON.stringify(c, null, 2));
```

## Output

```
// New B from A
{
  "val1": "a",
  "val2": "b"
}

// New C from A
{
  "val3": "c",
  "val4": "d",
  "val5": "e"
}
```